# Configure linux PC as a Router

Tags: networking, iptables

I want to configure my Rasberry Pi as a router. I have two network interfaces eth0 and eth1 connected to two networks. **eth0 is connected to a private** network and **eth1 is connected to a public** network (internet).

```
wan ----[router]--> [eth1 (Raspbery pi) eth0]<---->[router]<----> [(PC1)]
```

I did the following things to configure the Raspberry Pi as router:

```
Step 1:- enable forwarding in the kernel
echo 1 >> /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

step 2:- Set rules in iptables to perform natting and forwarding
# eth0 is LAN
# eth1 is WAN
# Masquerade.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
# fowarding
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# Allow outgoing connections from the LAN side.
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT
```

Now I am able to ping from  to WAN side router via the Raspberry Pi, and also I am able to ping Google IP (8.8.8.8) from PC1. But I was not able to browse any sites on PC1. Ping is working but other way of accessing Internet are not working. How can I debug this iptables to solve this issue? Where can the problem lie?

---

EDIT:- Here is the iptables vaules.

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/duser# iptables -t filter -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@raspberrypi:/home/duser# iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
root@raspberrypi:/home/duser# iptables -t mangle -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: are you able to ping 8.8.8.8 from PC1?

Comment: @KonradGajewski yes

Comment: Show me the entire iptable on the router (all tables).

Comment: @KonradGajewski I have edited with iptables values.

Comment: They all seem fine. What is the error you get on the PC?

Comment: I checked the internet connectivity with `sudo apt-get update` and it couldn't able to connect with server. I tried to launch `google.com` from web browser and i couldn't.

Comment: I'm not sure it is related to your router. Show me /etc/resolv.conf on PC1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you correctly set DNS server on PC? Can you ping www.google.com instead of 8.8.8.8? It looks like your PC cannot translate domain name to IP.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with nameserver. I set the 8.8.8.8 (Google Nameserver) in /etc/resolv.conf and everything worked good. Thank you.